# Could not find a part of the path when programatically mounting remote folder

Tags: asp.net

I am using the following code to mount a remote drive:

```
public static void MapDrive()
{
    try
    {
        if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(remoteFolder1)) //"Z:\\"
        {
            DisconnectDrive(remoteDriveLetter); //"Z:"
        }
        System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        p.StartInfo.FileName = "net.exe";
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = @" use " + remoteDriveLetter + " " + remoteShareName + " " + userPwd + " /user:" + userName;

        //EventLog.WriteEntry("Conversion Service", "Remote drive mapped successfully", EventLogEntryType.Information);

        p.Start();
        p.WaitForExit();
    }
    catch (Exception ex6_5)
    {
        WriteException(ex6_5, "Ex6.5");
    }
}
```

I can verify that that the Z drive is available and am able to save files to it by dragging but the following code throws an DirectoryNotFoundException "Could not find a part of the path 'Z:\Default.pptx'."

```
AsyncFileUpload1.SaveAs(remoteFolder + fileName);
```

The value in remoteFolder is "Z:\" and fileName is "Default.pptx".

Can someone help me out please?

Thanks,

Risho